# How to correctly align bibitems

Tags: horizontal-alignment, bibliographies, align

I am using the `thebibliography` environment. In addition I use custom labels, which are different in length. How do I align my `bibitems` correctly, so that all bib entries vertically start at the maximum width of the longest label? Pretty much I want the 'normal' `biblatex` behavior, but with the `thebibliography` environment. I can't use `biblatex` in this case.

Comment: In the mandatory argument for `thebibliography` use a string having the same width as the widest label; for example, if your widest label is, say `AZ908`, then use `\begin{thebibliography}{AZ908}`... ...\end{thebibliography}`.

Comment: Awesome! I thought the description was often times somewhat confusing what that mandatory argument is. Some people said it's the number of resources. If you write an answer post I can accept it.

Comment: If one is not allowed to use bibtex (e.g. because of the rules of the journal) one could start constructing the bibliography with bibtex and then, at the end, copy the content of the generated *.bbl file into the document. In this way one avoids sorting and formatting by hand.

Comment: @CluelessNewbie I added an answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the mandatory argument for `thebibliography` use a string having the same width as the widest label; for example, if your widest label is, say `AZ908`, then use

```
\begin{thebibliography}{AZ908}
...
\end{thebibliography}
```